# Wrapping 'simple form'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I cannot produce this output with *simple form*:

```
.row
  .checkbox.check-default
    %input#checkbox1{:checked => "checked", :type => "checkbox", :value => "1"}/
    %label{:for => "checkbox1"} Keep Me Signed in
```

My current wrapper:

```
config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, :tag => 'div', :class => 'checkbox check-default', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :label_input, :wrap_with => { :class => 'checkbox inline' }
end
```

**UPDATE**

I accidently overlooked the following:

```
  # Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
  # Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
  #   inline: input + label
  #   nested: label > input
  config.boolean_style = :inline
```

i had a second initializer... thanks for pointing me in the right direction..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert but keep in mind that `:label_input` outputs `label` and `input` together in default order. Maybe you should try:

```
config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, :tag => 'div', :class => 'checkbox check-default', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :input
  b.use :label
end
```

Comment: thanks for your hint! i completely overlooked a second initializer i used for simple_form... It did not solve but pointed in the right direction therefore i accept, i'll update the question....

Comment: If you are using simple_form with Zurb Foundation I've already solved checkbox issue here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Foundation-5-&-simple_form-3-check-boxes